# How to map a SignalR Hub in ASP.NET MVC Core to a dynamic route? (e.g. /controller/action/{id}?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

my question is simple and everything important is in my title.

I've tried to map it this way:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/Controller/Action/{id}");
});
```

But I get a 404 in my developer console in Chrome, when requesting such a route:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> signalr.js:1883 Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error (ConsoleLogger.log @ signalr.js:1883)
>
> Error: Failed to start the connection: Error (ConsoleLogger.log @ Signalr.js:1883)

Therefore I guess I am mapping it the wrong way?